# Usage of @NotNull annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I know that if I add the annotation **`@NotNull`** before a variable, then it could not be null. But it cannot fulfill my demand.

For example in my post JSON body I have a variable called "value". I want to achieve the following goal:
1. The variable "value" must exist in the post JSON body, following body is not acceptable:
 [image]
2. I must have the field "value" in my post body, but the value of it could be null. Following body is acceptable:
[image]

So **`@NotNull`** annotation cannot fulfill the second goal. So how can I do it?

Comment: You might want to mention somewhere you're talking about hibernate.

Comment: Why must `value` exist with a `null` representation?  It means it isn't provided, same as the first JSON stream you showed.  Not to mention that many JSON serialization products exclude empty and null values from the streams.

Comment: How is JSON deserialization made on the java side?

Comment: According to java json parsers as i known, json value is consider null when they missing in json body. If a field exists in json, it is considered as not null, so @NotNull annotation is not needed. In your case, i think you may want to try `@NotEmpty`